# How to make numpy array containing multidimensional arrays of different shape?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have some numpy arrays of size (2, 4, 11), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 15).

I want to make an single array (shape [1 * 3]) like this:

```
array([[array(size 2, 4, 11), array(size 2, 4, 5), array(size 2, 4, 15)]], dtype=object)
```

I tried to call `np.array([the list of arrays], dtype=object)`, but this error occured:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4,11) into shape (2,4)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but please be aware that doing so is very rarely useful and usually a mistake. Consider using a list instead, or maybe a 2x4x31 array.

Comment: When the first dimensions match, this process produces an error.  In this case you should go the safe route - make an 'blank' object dtype array of the right size, and assign the arrays to their respective elements.  Better yet, stick with a list of arrays.